# Pushing to remote with git in aptana3 via SSH

Tags: git, ssh, aptana, aptana3

I currently have trouble using Aptana's GUI to push to a remote git repository.

What I did:

1. Create a bare repository on my home server
2. Create a local repository and commit all my files
3. Add remote to git repository (I had to do this with the terminal, it didn't work with the GUI)
4. Push to the remote location (also with the terminal)

When I right-click on my project and select `team` -> `remotes` -> `Push current branch to` -> `myserver` Apatana opens a small window indicating it is doing something, but it never asks me for my ssh password and just does nothing. It's also impossible to close this window except by clicking "Run in background" (nothing happens when you click cancel or the "X").

If I use the terminal (from within Aptana) and execute `git push myserver`, it works flawlessly. It asks for the password and pushes the files to the remote repository.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem with using `team->remotes->push current branch to`
However, if tracking is set, which most likely is since `git push myserver` worked in the terminal, try using `team->push` which basically executes `git push`
If that does not work (some error message), add tracking by executing

```
git branch -u myserver/branch_name
```

replace `branch_name` with the branch name on the remote server (if it is master and you set up the remote to myserver, the command will be `git branch -u myserver/master`
After executing once, you should have no problem using `team->Push`and `team->Pull` directly